# Filter and plot values that satisfy a certain condition

Tags: excel, graph

The data comes from several sensors that arranged in columns, and each row represents a measurement instance (say, a 10-minute average).

I perform some filtering and get a 'Global criteria' column of `TRUE` and `FALSE` depending on whether the data met the criteria.

Now, I want to create an x-y plot that only portrays the data that fullfils the criteria; perhaps I am missing something blatantly obvious but I have not been able to produce this graph.

I have tried to create a 'Filtered' vector in the Name manager:

```
X is
=PRODUCT(GlobalCriteria;Data!$A:$A)
Y is
=PRODUCT(GlobalCriteria;Data!$B:$B)
```

to no avail...

Comment: can you show what your excel looks like

Comment: @pnuts, I did not mention that I need the data to be dynamic - the filters can be set at any time and the graph should reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a non-optimal solution, in that I multiply the boolean vector with the vector(s) I want to plot, and then plot that multiplication.  I get of course a lot of values at (0,0) but I can live with that.

I am of course looking for a more elegant solution, perhaps with dynamic names.